# How to configure Entity Framework 4 to prevent drop when generate database

Tags: .net, entity-framework, visual-studio-2010

is there any option when updating classes in EF4 Modeller to disable the drop
of all data and tables, just to append non existing fields and leave old tables and data
untouched.

I mean not to change every time on every little change to edit manual the SQL files.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do it with the "[Entity Designer Database Generation Power Pack](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/df3541c3-d833-4b65-b942-989e7ec74c87)." You can [read about this tool here](http://blogs.msdn.com/adonet/archive/2010/02/08/entity-designer-database-generation-power-pack.aspx).

Comment: i've installed it buy still no luck. tested it, but do you may know a blog or something with manual or instructions. still don't get rid of drop of tables or data within.

Comment: I linked the best walkthrough I know of in my answer. It has an example which preserves existing data. Did you try it?